# Azure WebJob fails: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, azure

How can I add DLL files to an Azure WebJob, or link to the DLL files that are readily available in the corresponding Azure AppService?

My WebJob is a Console application that is to run daily on a Cron schema.

When I test it manually, it fails with

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyIISApp, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But I cannot select multiple files in the Azure WebJob file upload process.

I have already tried to upload the EXE file to my Azure AppService alongside the DLLs, but I cannot select this EXE file for Execution anywhere in the WebJobs tab - it always wants a single file upload.

Comment: This happens when you upload it through visual studio?

Comment: This happens when I upload the EXE file through the web form in the Azure portal.

Comment: Did you try the visual studio? Right click on the project and click publish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upload a .zip file instead of a .exe file. The zip must contains all required files (exe, dll(s), etc.)